# How to resize images in JScrollPane as frame resizes

Tags: java, image, resize, scrollpane

I need to develop an image gallery of sorts, where I can display images in a JFrame, and I can scroll and double click to expand to full screen etc. I was able to display the images the way I want it, but when I resize the JFrame, the images gets cut off as there is no horizontal scroll.

Is there a way where I can have have vertical scroll and when frame resizes, the panel within will resize to fit horizontally?

```
try {
    
    BufferedImage readImage = ImageIO.read(new File("myFile.png"));
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(readImage, "png", bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(bis);
    
    JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
    imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,2,5,5));
    for (int x=0;x<8;++x){
        JLabel l = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
        imagePanel.add(l);
    }
    
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(mainPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.add(scrollPane);
    //frame.add(imagePanel); //This will work as i intended it to be, but there is no vertical scroll
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Edit:

A visual example is shown below. When the frame resizes, the images get cropped, what I would like instead are for the images within the JScrollPane to resize so that it could all fit horizontally, while at the same time maintaining the vertical scroll.

[image: cropped images]

Edit2:

Using [StretchIcon](http://www.camick.com/java/source/StretchIcon.java), I was able to achieve having the images resize dynamically, but this introduced another issue where there are huge spaces in between the images as I resize.

[image: large gaps]

Comment: Not really sure I understand the question but maybe you can: 1) use the [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/). I Icon will automaticallylresize based on the space available and 2) use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/) It allows you to fix the width of the panel to the width of the viewport of the scroll pane.

Comment: @camickr I've edited my question with images to illustrate what the issue I am facing

Comment: More or less what I thought so it doesn't change my answer.

Comment: @camickr, Thank you for the answer. I tried using the stretch icon but it introduced another issue. There are huge gaps when I resize. I'm not too familiar with layouts and insets etc, so I'm not too sure what is causing this issue. (edited qns to illustrate)

Comment: The StretchIcon will either 1) resize to fill the space available or 2) keep the original width/height ratio. In the second case if the width shrinks then the height will also shrink which would cause the gap.